# error on importing mac project on windows in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am importing project in Android studio which is built on Mac. But when I import this project I got this error:

*error code 42 unable to open png file*.

I google it then I came to know due to long project path it created problem. Therefore I rename long path to short. Now I am getting this error:

*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processBetaDebugResources'.*  with error code as `1073741819`.

Comment: Android studio 1.0 RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After change the version of buildTools to

```
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
```

solves my issue.